# Apache Spark: Percentile of list of row values in dataframe

Tags: list, dataframe, pyspark

I have an Apache Spark dataframe with a set of computed columns.  For each row in the dataframe (approx 2000), I wish to take the row values for 10 columns and locate the closest value of an 11th column relative to those other 10.

I would imagine I would take those row values and turn it into a list then use an abs value calculation to determine the closest.

But I am stuck on how to turn the row values into a list.  I've taken a column and turned those values into a list using collect_list but not sure how to handle when the list comes from a single row and multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

You should `explode` your columns so you can linearize your computations.

Let's create a sample dataframe:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = sc.parallelize([np.random.randint(0, 10, 11).tolist() for _ in range(20)])\
    .toDF(["col" + str(i) for i in range(1, 12)])
df.show()
    +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
    |col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10|col11|
    +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
    |   5|   0|   3|   3|   7|   9|   3|   5|   2|    4|    7|
    |   6|   8|   8|   1|   6|   7|   7|   8|   1|    5|    9|
    |   8|   9|   4|   3|   0|   3|   5|   0|   2|    3|    8|
    |   1|   3|   3|   3|   7|   0|   1|   9|   9|    0|    4|
    |   7|   3|   2|   7|   2|   0|   0|   4|   5|    5|    6|
    |   8|   4|   1|   4|   9|   8|   1|   1|   7|    9|    9|
    |   3|   6|   7|   2|   0|   3|   5|   9|   4|    4|    6|
    |   4|   4|   3|   4|   4|   8|   4|   3|   7|    5|    5|
    |   0|   1|   5|   9|   3|   0|   5|   0|   1|    2|    4|
    |   2|   0|   3|   2|   0|   7|   5|   9|   0|    2|    7|
    |   2|   9|   2|   3|   3|   2|   3|   4|   1|    2|    9|
    |   1|   4|   6|   8|   2|   3|   0|   0|   6|    0|    6|
    |   3|   3|   8|   8|   8|   2|   3|   2|   0|    8|    8|
    |   3|   8|   2|   8|   4|   3|   0|   4|   3|    6|    9|
    |   8|   0|   8|   5|   9|   0|   9|   6|   5|    3|    1|
    |   8|   0|   4|   9|   6|   5|   7|   8|   8|    9|    2|
    |   8|   6|   6|   9|   1|   6|   8|   8|   3|    2|    3|
    |   6|   3|   6|   5|   7|   0|   8|   4|   6|    5|    8|
    |   2|   3|   9|   7|   5|   3|   4|   5|   3|    3|    7|
    |   9|   9|   9|   7|   3|   2|   3|   9|   7|    7|    5|
    +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+
```

There are several ways to turn row values into a list:

- creating a `map` with keys equal to column names and values equal to the corresponding row value.

  ```py
  import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
  from itertools import chain
  df = df\
      .withColumn("id", psf.monotonically_increasing_id())\
      .select(
          "id", 
          psf.posexplode(
              psf.create_map(list(chain(*[(psf.lit(c), psf.col(c)) for c in df.columns if c != "col11"])))
          ).alias("pos", "col_name", "value"), "col11")
  df.show()
      +---+---+--------+-----+-----+
      | id|pos|col_name|value|col11|
      +---+---+--------+-----+-----+
      |  0|  0|    col1|    5|    7|
      |  0|  1|    col2|    0|    7|
      |  0|  2|    col3|    3|    7|
      |  0|  3|    col4|    3|    7|
      |  0|  4|    col5|    7|    7|
      |  0|  5|    col6|    9|    7|
      |  0|  6|    col7|    3|    7|
      |  0|  7|    col8|    5|    7|
      |  0|  8|    col9|    2|    7|
      |  0|  9|   col10|    4|    7|
      |  1|  0|    col1|    6|    9|
      |  1|  1|    col2|    8|    9|
      |  1|  2|    col3|    8|    9|
      |  1|  3|    col4|    1|    9|
      |  1|  4|    col5|    6|    9|
      |  1|  5|    col6|    7|    9|
      |  1|  6|    col7|    7|    9|
      |  1|  7|    col8|    8|    9|
      |  1|  8|    col9|    1|    9|
      |  1|  9|   col10|    5|    9|
      +---+---+--------+-----+-----+
  ```
- Using a `StructType` inside an `ArrayType`

  ```py
  df = df\
      .withColumn("id", psf.monotonically_increasing_id())\
      .select(
          "id", 
          psf.explode(
              psf.array([psf.struct(psf.lit(c).alias("col_name"), psf.col(c).alias("value")) 
                         for c in df.columns if c != "col11"])).alias("cols"), 
          "col11").select("cols.*", "col11", "id")
  df.show()
      +--------+-----+-----+---+
      |col_name|value|col11| id|
      +--------+-----+-----+---+
      |    col1|    5|    7|  0|
      |    col2|    0|    7|  0|
      |    col3|    3|    7|  0|
      |    col4|    3|    7|  0|
      |    col5|    7|    7|  0|
      |    col6|    9|    7|  0|
      |    col7|    3|    7|  0|
      |    col8|    5|    7|  0|
      |    col9|    2|    7|  0|
      |   col10|    4|    7|  0|
      |    col1|    6|    9|  1|
      |    col2|    8|    9|  1|
      |    col3|    8|    9|  1|
      |    col4|    1|    9|  1|
      |    col5|    6|    9|  1|
      |    col6|    7|    9|  1|
      |    col7|    7|    9|  1|
      |    col8|    8|    9|  1|
      |    col9|    1|    9|  1|
      |   col10|    5|    9|  1|
      +--------+-----+-----+---+
  ```
- using an `ArrayType`...

Once you have an exploded list, you can look for the minimum value of `|col11 - value|`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(psf.abs(psf.col("col11") - psf.col("value")))
res = df.withColumn("rn", psf.row_number().over(w)).filter("rn = 1")
res.sort("id").show()
    +--------+-----+-----+----------+---+
    |col_name|value|col11|        id| rn|
    +--------+-----+-----+----------+---+
    |    col5|    7|    7|         0|  1|
    |    col2|    8|    9|         1|  1|
    |    col1|    8|    8|         2|  1|
    |    col2|    3|    4|         3|  1|
    |    col1|    7|    6|         4|  1|
    |    col5|    9|    9|         5|  1|
    |    col2|    6|    6|         6|  1|
    |   col10|    5|    5|         7|  1|
    |    col3|    5|    4|         8|  1|
    |    col6|    7|    7|         9|  1|
    |    col2|    9|    9|8589934592|  1|
    |    col3|    6|    6|8589934593|  1|
    |    col3|    8|    8|8589934594|  1|
    |    col2|    8|    9|8589934595|  1|
    |    col2|    0|    1|8589934596|  1|
    |    col2|    0|    2|8589934597|  1|
    |    col9|    3|    3|8589934598|  1|
    |    col7|    8|    8|8589934599|  1|
    |    col4|    7|    7|8589934600|  1|
    |    col4|    7|    5|8589934601|  1|
    +--------+-----+-----+----------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks. So once I have a column with a list of these values, is it possible to calculate percentiles of this list?

Comment: You can directly look for the minimum value of the absolute value of the difference using a window function.